# JSON database update via JQuery-Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

Looking for a solution to call and update access DB (or any DB for that matter) in JQuery Mobile. something in the form of a plugin like the popular dataTables for JQuery, only MOBILE version. The backend already exist and can be JSON or JSONP.

In other words based on the json received it would dynamically create all views and input fields.

I know this sounds like I'm shopping for an app designer, but I just feel like something is already out there for this popular request. I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Having visited http://editor.datatables.net/ using my phone, the component works pretty well already. How is it not fulfilling your requirements?

Comment: I think I'm reconsidering my question... what I really want is my data query via json to return in editable fields that update changes... I have not started my project yet, but have 18 different data sources (all json) that are different in structure. I need to create a dynamic front end that will accommodate various fields, but allow for mass update.

Comment: I'm not on a shopping expedition, just looking for a starting point to design what is best accommodate various data sources.

Comment: @Richard A. - datatables.net not in JQM look and feel?

Comment: Moved to new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320309/modify-json-received-and-post-back-update