# Modify JSON received and POST back update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Looking for a starting point. I'm getting my data (via json) for a JQM page. I need to be able to edit any of the returned result fields and UPDATE the database via .post json.

My thought is to iterate through the json array, make changes and post json array back, should I be populating text-boxes in the initial load and then creating separate array?

```
$.getJSON('JSON_MDB.php',
    function (data) {  
        // data is now JSON object instantiated from retrieved info
        $.each( data, function ( i, val ) {

            ($('<div>')
            .attr({
                'data-role': 'collapsible',
                'data-content-theme': 'c',
                'data-collapsed': 'true',
                'id': 'cResults'
            })
            .html('<h4>' + this.lastName + ', ' + this.firstName + '</h4><ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Choices..." data-inset="true" id="makecollapsibleul"><li>' 
            + 'FDID: ' + this.FDID + '</li><li>'
            + 'Choice 1: ' + this.C1 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 2: ' + this.C2 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 3: ' + this.C3 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 4: ' + this.C4 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 5: ' + this.C5 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 6: ' + this.C6 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'IP: ' + this.IPADDRESS + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Pick Date: ' + this.PICKDATE + '</li></ul>'
            ))
            .appendTo('#primary');

            $('#makecollapsible').collapsibleset().trigger('create');
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

        });
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">      
    <div data-role="header">         
        <h1>MCFRSIT JSON DATA</h1>     
    </div><!-- /header -->      

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="outer-ul">
            <li>  
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h4>Submitted Choices</h4> 
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="makecollapsible">
                        <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>           
    </div><!-- /content -->      

    <div data-role="footer">              
    </div>

</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: On a "good programming" note, you can group var declarations with a single `var` statement, and then `,` instead of `;` to separate the vars. Also, don't create choice1, choice2, etc. Creating an array or structured object is much cleaner.

Comment: sorry very new to this: can you provide example?

Comment: you already actually have it in your code: that `this` object is a nicely structured object, you don't need to unpack it to a million individual variables, simply do `'Choice 1: ' + this.C1 + '</li><li>'` etc.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I had that in my current code, I overlooked it in this example code... anyway.. any idea about my original question?

Comment: the thing you want, from your description, sounds independent of your visualisation of the data, so I'm not sure this is actually a very useful question (it's mostly asking for opinions on the matter). I'd say make your update UI independent, with a function `updateHTML(obj)` that you can call whenever you like, to update the HTML. That way you can play around with when to call it, and simply test the various places where it might make sense to find the best user experience.